# Finding the magnitude a matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help. I have a list of 3 x 3  matrices of real numbers.I want to find how close each of these matrices are to a {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}} matrix. Any suggestions to a method algorithm or code?

Comment: Is this a question about the software Mathematica?

Comment: Take their Frobenius norm.

Comment: The matrices are diagonally dominant. when I inspected the result, the  Frobenius norm does not seem to show their true physical meaning of their deviation from a matrix of zeros

Comment: You should specify your norm - what is the measure/definition of "closeness"?

Comment: So a matrix of ones (1) is closer than a matrix of (5)s

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you characterise the matrix. Let say you can define it in terms of sum of absolute values of the element.

```
norm1[m_List] := Total@Flatten@Abs[m]
```

Or you can define it as `Norm` of diagonal elements

```
norm2[m_List] := Norm@Diagonal[m]
```

Given a matrix `m`

```
m = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {3, 3}]
```

> {{-2.72364, 2.26668, 4.07867}, {-1.8835, 0.968504, 1.47028}, {4.15286,
>      2.12865, 3.64299}}

This would be its 'length'

```
norm1[m]
```

> 23.3158

```
norm2[m]
```

> 4.65055

There can be a better answer if you can specify your exact problem.